# Send SMS through internet to another country

Tags: wi-fi, sms

I came to Europe from Canada for a month, but I want to keep in touch with relatives and friends back in Canada. Assuming I have WiFi access on my Android, how can I text them, and be able to receive texts back? Texting overseas would be too expensive for both me and them, so I must find a way to do it through WiFi, but they would receive and send actual texts.

I have a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to send and receive SMS messages over Wi-Fi, I would suggestion using Google Voice (Now integrated into Google Hangouts). You will be able to send/receive SMS free of charge (As long as you are using Wi-Fi). I have done some quick Googling, and didn't see anything that says it doesn't work in Canada. Give it a shot and see if it works for you.

If for any reason it doesn't work in your region, feel free to let me know and I will try and find other services that may be of use to you.

Comment: yep its what i use for calling, its the best. they recently added google dialer, but i dont see any way i can text through it

Comment: Where are you using the service? Google Voice Website or app, or through the Hangouts service?

Comment: i tried it in hangouts, it was a while ago i noticed i can only call and not text. ill try to do a little more research, but i dont see a way to do it

Comment: what you looked at is probably to use hangouts as a texting app, rather than an app that sends texts throguh wifi

Comment: Try using the Google Voice app maybe. And when using Hangouts, usually, you just type in the phone number you want to SMS on the Contacts tab within the app, and it will prompt you asking if you would like to send the message with Hangouts or Google Voice SMS. Check in your app settings at Settings->Current Google Account-> Incoming Phone Calls & Messages. Make sure those two options are checked and see if that helps. EDIT: The app indeed sends full SMS messages via my Google Number, free of charge. I use it daily to text friends, as I have a limited texting plan on my phone currently.

Comment: i dont ssee incoming phone calls and messages anywhere in the options. please help me further, i really need this to work. googl voice was replaced by hangouts dialer? i only see it allowing me to call not text

Comment: maybe the andorid app dossnt have texting, i would do it through the web

Comment: The Android app does include SMS. It may not be available in your region though. I will do more research and try and help you futher. Please be patient...

Comment: After some research, it turns out that Google Voice SMS services are not available in Canada. Only US users can use it.  I will search for another service that may be of use to you.

Comment: I have found 2 free SMS services that may work in your area. FreeTone is the 1st: http://www.free-tone.com/. NextPlus is the 2nd: http://nextplus.me/. Give both of them a try and see if the work for you. Hopefully these will work.

Comment: freetone didnt work, but nxextplus seemsz to work. i hope it wont randomly lock out and say i have to pay to keep using it. This seems to be the most accurate answer, involving an app that only works in us and one that works in canada too. ill accept it. Thank you for your effort

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. As far as I am aware, NextPlus does not require any kind of subscription. You can pay to remove ads, and you can pay to send!/receive phone calls I believe, but texting is free forever. Hope you enjoy your stay at Europe!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Canada, but here in the UK some carriers have apps that let you use your WiFi connection to send texts and receive using your normal phone number. I'm not sure about using this overseas but you could probably use a proxy (like [Hola](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hola)) if this is blocked. Even if an app exists but you cannot receive texts with it then this is generally free when roaming because you have no control over who sends you an SMS.

Comment: we should have that too. im having trouble finding it on the site. whats the feature called?

Comment: You might not have a similar feature but if you do, then I don't there is a general term for this - every carrier has there own. For example, 3 in the UK has Three inTouch (http://www.three.co.uk/discover/three_intouch). I can see that Canadian home-phone providers have their own versions (TELUS Extend and Rogers One Number)

Comment: To see if your network has a similar service just google '[your network name] wifi calling/sms app'

Answer (score 0):

Use Viber or Whats App? There are also numerous of app similar to them.
Typical SMS is impossible, because it's send over your telephone carrier.

Comment: so i'd be able to send messages but not receive them?

Comment: No...telephone companies have agreement with each others where if you are in one country and want to send to other company,you'll sms first travels to your registered carrier,then to other telephone carrier who's in receivers country, and finally to the telephone where is the receiver.This is a lot more complicated, but I have tried to explain it to you as easier I can, so you could understand. But your problem solver is one of these apps. They are multi platform,so iOS,Android and Windows support them+you can send anyone anywhere in the world but you and the receiver must have internet access